# Parity of number of solutions to Diophantine equations

Tags: nt.number-theory, lo.logic, diophantine-equations, computational-number-theory, decidability

By $MRDP$ resolution of Hilbert's tenth, we infer, counting number of solutions to Diophantine equations is undecidable.

Is parity of number of solutions to Diophantine equations undecidable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While it’s unclear what you mean by “parity” when the number of solutions is infinite, all such questions have been answered by M. Davis, *On the number of solutions of Diophantine equations*, Proc. AMS 35 (1972), 552–554, [doi link](https://doi.org/10.2307/2037646):

> **Theorem:** Fix $\varnothing\subsetneq A\subsetneq\omega\cup\{\aleph_0\}$. Then it is undecidable whether the number of solutions of a given Diophantine equation belongs to $A$.